# Makefile variables

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have a variable which is
number=$(shell seq 1 50).
I need this sequence but avoiding the last element in a particular loop. How can I do it? Because the only working solution is introducig it manually but that is not what I am looking for.

I tried several options but none seems to work and I would like to have it automatised instead for the case that the limist where to be changed.

Comment: This depends entirely on how you're using the variable.  Please provide a small, complete reproducible example of what you want to do.

Comment: Why not just use a second variable `number1=$(shell seq 1 49)`?

Comment: in gnu make syntax `@for n in $(subst $(lastword $(number)),,$(number)); do echo $$n; done` will print all elements excepting the last one. Btw, it's easier to do in shell

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems like it may be cleaner to just store `50` in the variable and generate the loop as needed. But since you've provided no code it's not really possible to know.

Answer (score 0):

In GNU Make, we can do this:

```
butlast = $(filter-out $(lastword $(1)),$(1))

numbers=$(shell seq 1 10)

$(info $$(numbers) == $(numbers))
$(info $$(call butlast,$$(numbers)) == $(call butlast,$(numbers)))

.PHONY: all

all:
        echo "hey"
```

Run:

```
$ make
$(numbers) == 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$(call butlast,$(numbers)) == 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
echo "hey"
hey
```

**Caveat:** `butlast` depends on the items in the list being unique. So its name tells a lie. It uses `filter-out`, which just removes all matching items. In the above example we are filtering out `10` which occurs only once. If `10` occurred in other places in the list, those would be gone too, but it's not a problem with the output of `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the shorter list first and append the last element to compute the full list:

```
$ cat Makefile
max   := 10
short := $(shell seq 1 `expr $(max) - 1`)
long  := $(short) $(max)

.PHONY: all

all:
    $(info short = $(short))
    $(info long = $(long))

$ make
short = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
long = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```